# ListView is hiding my Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to solve this problem but I didn't found anything that helps me.

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_lv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In which I want to show a fragment below the listview. In code it is like this (Code for `ListActivity`:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new BottomMenuFragment()).commit();
// Populate lisview and set adapter
```

But when I run the app, the fragment is not shown, I think the problem is with the attribute `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the `ListView` `list_lv`. But I have not idea of how to solve it. Here is an screenshot with multiple data in the list:

[image]

And with few items:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the listview above the framelayout. Remove android:layout_below="@id/list_lv" from FrameLayout and add android:layout_above="@id/container" to LinearLayout. Below is th ecode snippet:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_above="@id/container"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you adding more elements ?

Comment: To the list View, It works great if the items in the listview fits in the screen. If I add more, the fragment is gone.

Comment: Can I know why are you placing ListView in a LinearLayout ? Any specific reason ? If not remove the LinearLayout and add the layout_above attribute to the listview itself. It will definitely work. :)

Comment: For the background, but I didn't remember I can set a background to the `ListView` too. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this xml layout basically will help you :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_lv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works fine, but I would like to keep the `RelativeLayout`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Sure it will solve your issue:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"        
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">   

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Vote if it works fine!